# Cannot assign an Action property

Tags: c#, func

Must be going crazy here but I can't see what I'm doing wrong in the following code to cause the syntax error

> CS0828: Cannot assign 'method group' to anonymous type property

I can't see anything anonymous about the code, the property has a name. The method I assign it it is named etc.

```
    // A basic function that takes an int and has void return
    private static void DoSomething(int d) 
    {
        // .... do stuff
    };

    // A class is defined with an Action<int> delegate
    private class XX
    {
        public Action<int> YY { get; set; }
    }

    // An instance of the class which clearly assigns a known method to the property
    private static readonly XX xx = new
    {
        // error "CS0828: Cannot assign 'method group' to anonymous type property"
        YY = DoSomething
    };
```

Comment: Just type classname after new keyword `private static readonly XX xx = new XX { YY = DoSomething };`

Comment: Thanks!  I was going crazy there.  I normally leave it off as I thought the type would have been implied from the type defined earlier on the line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You confused [target-typed `new` expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-new) with [anonymous types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/anonymous-types)!

`new { ... }` creates an anonymous type, so `YY` there is a property of the anonymous type, so the compiler doesn't know what delegate type it should convert the method group into.

You should use `new() { ... }` instead, which creates an object of the target type `XX`, and also uses an object initialiser to initialise it.

While object initialisers normally allow you to omit `()` when there are no constructor parameters, target-typed `new` expressions always require `()`, regardless of whether you are using an object initialiser. Otherwise, the syntax would conflict with anonymous types!

Comment: Thanks!  I'm so used to just putting "new" and knew that "new()" could also be used but never realised the subtle difference between the two.  The latter is strongly typed.

Answer (score 0):

you should `create an instance of the XX` class and then assign the method to the YY property:

```
    private static readonly XX xx = new XX
    {
        // error "CS0828: Cannot assign 'method group' to anonymous type property"
        YY = DoSomething
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

More eleborations on Sweeper answers.

In C#, `new { }` is used to create an instance of an anonymous type, which is a type defined at runtime without a formal class declaration.

Therefore, when you have used `new { YY = DoSomething }`, you are creating an anonymous type instance with a property named `YY`, and you're trying to assign the `DoSomething` method pointer to it ,BUT it have nothing to do with your class XX and it's properties it is new seperated class.

To create an instance of your class `XX` and assign the DoSomething method to its `YY` property.

You should use `new XX { }` to explicitly create an object of type `XX` because otherwise, without new `XX`, you're creating something that doesn't have the `YY`. This approach is called a target-typed new expression.

`new XX { }`  this is creating type on the fly   (WHAT YOU WANT)
`new {}` this creating annomoys object on the fly also :D  (WHAT WAS WRONG)

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are 3 solutions to fix the compile error:

```
// Object initializer with optional constructor parentheses
XX xx = new XX() { YY = DoSomething };
    
// Object initializer without constructor parentheses
XX xx = new XX { YY = DoSomething };

// Target-typed new expression together with object initializer
XX xx = new() { YY = DoSomething };
```

Comment: Yeah, the whole C# business surrounding needing the parantheses/type name or not regarding newing object instances is a good example of how _not_ to design the syntax of a language. And perhaps toss the var keyword into the mix for even more fun... I can't decide whether i should laugh or cry, i'll probably going to do both. ;-)

Comment: @EyesShriveledToRaisins: Yes, there is some confusion around flexible and optional features of C# as a fast evolving language. This leads to a trade-off between flexibility and simplicity of the language and raises the learning curve. But I am often happy with the flexibility of programming languages anyway and love C#.

Comment: What flexibility benefit is to have that would justify this kind of muddled grammar? Heck, allowing myself to be facetious, i almost expect a future C# version will make the curly braces of object initializers optional, allowing something like `XX xx = new XX YY = DoSomething, ZZ = 42;` or `XX xx = new() YY = DoSomething, ZZ = 42;` so programmers can avoid typing even more redundant characters. ;-)